# NextJS hosted on Vercel 504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, serverless, vercel

I'm having a silly error with Vercel and NextJS and it's giving me a headache. I have a simple NextJS application with api routes and when I call my hello world endpoint (or any other endpoint) it's giving me the following:

[image]

[image]

The errors just say the task timed out, not what's causing it. It doesn't make sense that it times out because all it does is return a string. On localhost, the app works perfectly and all endpoints work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction what it could be, or how I could figure out what the problem is?

The function:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

Comment: Can you show use your serverless function?

Comment: @Jax-p I added the function to my post. It's just a default function from Next I think.

Comment: Looks good to me. You might try their [Execution timeout checklist](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions#execution-timeout).

Comment: @Jax-p I have no clue what it could be, very weird. Normally it's a time out but this function isn't slow at all.

Comment: did you have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

It is what Jax-p says, the endpoint duration was 10.03s and the maximum for the hobbie account is 10s.  If you have the pro or enterprise version, you can create a vercel.json file and assign the maximum duration:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "pages/*.tsx": {
      "maxDuration": 45 // This function can run for a maximum of 30 seconds
    },
    "api/test.js": {
      "maxDuration": 30 // This function can run for a maximum of 30 seconds
    },
    "api/hello.js": {
      "maxDuration": 15 // This function can run for a maximum of 15 seconds
    }
  }
}
```

How to configure: https://vercel.com/docs/functions/configuring-functions/duration

Max duration for each type account: https://vercel.com/docs/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes#max-duration